# Structure issue C (Declaration)

Tags: arrays, c, declaration, return-type, function-definition

lets suppose that we have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    int CNE;
}etudiant;
etudiant saisie(){
    etudiant T[5];
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<5;i++){
        
        printf("Le CNE : ");
        scanf("%d",T[i].CNE);
        
    }
    return T;
}
int main(){
    etudiant e = saisie();
    return 0;
}
```

i want to have 100 Student so i cant declare 100 student and then put their CNE right ?
so what is the easy way to declare them

Comment: What do you mean by `return T[5];`? This will attempt to return the 6th student (because array indices start from 0) from `T`, which is an array of 5 students.

Comment: What does "not work " mean?  We can't help you if you do not provide enough detail

Comment: @ForceBru it doesnt run the code if i did return T

Comment: You can't return an array that's been declared as a local variable. Either declare it global, or use malloc.

Comment: @user14655248, yeah, but you're trying to return something that doesn't exist. Since you need to allocate the array inside a function, you wouldn't be able to just return `T` since it'll be destroyed on function exit. You should look into dynamic memory allocation and the `malloc` function.

Comment: when i run the code [Error] could not convert '(etudiant*)(& T)' from 'etudiant*' to 'etudiant'

Comment: With `%d`, you need to pass a pointer to int.  But `T[i].CNE` is an int.

Answer (score 1):

To make your program meaningful it should be rewritten for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int CNE;
}etudiant;

void saisie( etudiant *e, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf("Le CNE : ");
        scanf("%d", &e[i].CNE);
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    etudiant e[N];

    saisie( e, N );

    return 0;
}
```

As for your program then at least the function return type is invalid

```
etudiant saisie();
```

because the function returns an array that is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

So you need at least to declare it like

```
etudiant * saisie();
```

But on the other hand, you may not return a local array with automatic storage duration because it will not be alive after exiting the function. So the returned pointer will be invalid.

If you want to create an array within the function and to return it to the caller you need to allocate it dynamically like for example

```
etudiant *e = malloc( 5 * sizeof( etudiant ) );
```

Or in this call

```
scanf("%d",T[i].CNE)
```

you need to use a pointer to the data member CNE like

```
scanf("%d", &T[i].CNE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the return type of the function doesn't match the type of the expression you're trying to return:

```
etudiant saisie(){
  etudiant T[5];  
  ...
  return T;
}
```

The *expression* `T` has type `etudiant [5]`, which in this context "decays" to type `edutiant *`.  `etudiant *` is not the same type as `etudiant`.

A second problem is that C functions cannot return *arrays*.  You cannot declare a C function to return an array type, and because of the decay rule when you try to return an array expression all that gets returned is a pointer to the first element of the array - unfortunately, the array ceases to exist once the function returns.

If you want to declare 100 students, just declare an array of `etudiant` in `main`:

```
#define NUM_STUDENTS 100
...
etudiant arr[NUM_STUDENTS];
```

If you want a function to modify or initialize the array, pass the array (*along with its size!*) as an argument to the function:

```
void saisie( etudiant *arr, size_t arrSize )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < arrSize; i++ )
  {
    printf( "Le CNE: " );
    scanf( "%d", &arr[i].CNE );
  }
}
```

which you would call from `main` as

```
saisie( arr, 100 );
```